# Laravel и ajax фильтр на Angular

Tags: laravel5, angular5

Реализовал ajax пагинацию на Angular 5, сам пагинатор использовал из библиотеки angular material, в качестве бекенда на проекте использую Laravel, все отлично работает

```
 public function index($countOrders,$indexPagination)
    {
        $slice = $countOrders * $indexPagination;
        $json = DB::table('orders')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->skip($slice)->take($countOrders)->get();
        $json = json_decode($json);
        return $json;
    }
```

Но сейчас стала задача реализовать фильтр, который должен работать по одному полю для введения запроса, и искать по нескольким полям в БД + нужно отфильтрованные данные резать для пагинатора. Вопрос - как можно реализовать сие чудо, возможно не в SQL запросе, а уже как-то получать все данные из бд и оперировать ими. P.s я недавно работаю с Laravel и с пыхой не особо дружу. Пожалуйста, любые идеи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Документация по пагинации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination)

Собственно, имеется метод `paginate($countOrders)`, запрос же будет формироваться в виде /url?page=$indexPagination
то есть вы можете написать, что-то в таком духе

```
public function index($countOrders)
{
   $json = DB::table('orders')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate($countOrders);

   return $json;// laravel сам вернет json для ajax-запрос, только структура будет другая в соответствии с документацией
}
```

По поводу фильтрации, если я правильно понимаю ваш вопрос, то вам нужно просто добавить метод `where` в ваш запрос, например:

```
DB::table('orders')->where('user_id', 12)->orderBy('id', 'desc')-paginate($countOrders);
```

[Формирование sql-запроса](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: А чем Вам не понравился этот вариант для пагинации? ->skip($slice)->take($countOrders), как по мне - более практично

Comment: Написал  `public function index($countOrders,$indexPagination,$searchValue)
        {
            $slice = $countOrders * $indexPagination;
            $search = "%".$searchValue."%";
            $json = DB::table('orders')->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->where('id', 'like', $search)
            ->orWhere('name', 'like', $search)
            ->orWhere('email', 'like', $search)
            ->orWhere('status', 'like', $search)
            ->skip($slice)->take($countOrders)->get();
            $json = json_decode($json);
            return $json;
        } ` пока отлично работает